# Why javaFX application jar runs on jdk but not on jre?

Tags: java, jar, javafx

I've my JavaFX app that calls some JNI code, uses a preloader jar and is compiled using jdk 1.7.
Now when I run jar on another computer with JRE7, by:

1. Double clicking jar: it starts but cannot load the JNI code containing libraries and therefore gets stuck.
2. Running jar via terminal using "java -jar ": App runs completely normal!
3. Now if I install jdk on this machine,
   it runs fine even with double click!

Can somebody tell me what is difference in these 3 cases?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add logging to your program, so that you can figure out why your JAR file doesn't execute properly.

You should look into if your manifest file is correct - there is a classpath in there you might want to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with the fact that JavaFX is not fully released with Java 1.7, but included more as a developer preview.

Also, JavaFX packaging and deployment is a little different than standard Java.  There is a new utility called 'javafxpackager' that should be used when packaging JavaFX applications.  Check out the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm